# How to make javascript work to response to buttons added later in AJAX way

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

i have a form to submit message. I'd like to submit in an `AJAX` way. the following code works, but the newly add 'reply' button doesn't work:

```
      {% block body %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.form.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#message_form").ajaxForm(function () {
            var messageid = '';
            var messagepubdate = 0;
            // GET NEWEST MESSAGE ID
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_get_new_message', function (data) {
                messageid = data.messageid;
                messagepubdate = data.messagepubdate;
                //alert(messageid); //TESTED! the messageid is the newly added message's _id!
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = "<li><img src='{{ g.get_user(g.user._id).email|gravatar(size=48)}}'><p> " +
                 "<strong><a href='{{url_for('user_timeline', username=g.user._id)}}'>{{ g.user._id}}</a></strong>&nbsp; " + $('#new_message').val()
                 + "<small>&mdash; " + messagepubdate + "</small><p align='right' style='text-align: right'><small><a href='#' data-messageid='#replies" + messageid + "' class='reply'>Reply</a></small></p><p><br /><div class='replies hidden' id='replies" + messageid + "'></div></p></p></li>";
                $('ul#messages').prepend(div);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

for old messages, the following scripts works well to toggle the replies div:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(function () {
        $('a.reply').click(function () {
            messageid = $(this).attr('data-messageid');
            $(messageid).text('loading');
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_get_replies', { messageid: messageid.substring(8) }, function (data) {
                $(messageid).html(data.result);
                $(messageid).slideToggle(0);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official jQuery 1.7 answer is [`jQuery.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

You can use `jQuery.on` to subscribe to *any* event, and you can use `jQuery.off` to unsubscribe.

To listen to all of the clicks for an element matching `a.reply`, regardless of when it was added to the document, you could use the following code:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'a.reply', function() { /* ... */ });
```

Likewise, you could use

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.reply', function() { /* ... */ });
```

Basically, the `$('body')` is the *context* to which the event listener is added. So in reality, jQuery is waiting for any event to bubble up to the `body` element, and checking to see if that event is a `click` event. If it is, and the element which gerenated the click event matched the `a.reply` selector, then jQuery will fire the delegate you passed as the third parameter.

If we just did this:

```
$('a.reply').on('click', function() { /* ... */ });
```

It would work the same way, but *only* listen to the events generated by the the elements *originally selected* by the `a.reply` selection. Therefore, any new elements added to the dom afterward would not be included. And, because we didn't add a selector to the `on` method, it will not listen for child events.

*Edit*

In previous versions of jQuery, you would use [`jQuery.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), which works in a similar, if not the exact same fashion. In jQuery 1.7, `jQuery.live` simply wraps `jQuery.on`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to attach events to elements that are likely to be added in the future (via Ajax) then you should always use event delegation.

In simple terms it works by attaching an event to the parent element and then checking to see which child was clicked. It doesn't matter if child elements are added or removed.

The correct way to use delegation in jQuery is with the .on() and .off() methods:

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

.live() and delegate() have been deprecated in favour of this new syntax.

In fact, jQuery now just passes calls to those functions straight through to .on() and .off()

```
live: function( types, data, fn ) {
        jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );
        return this;
    }

delegate: function( selector, types, data, fn ) {
        return this.on( types, selector, data, fn );
    }
```

Note: This is not only useful in Ajax applications. If you have a table with 1000 rows for example, it is far more efficent to use a delegated event on the table itself, rather than attaching to 100s of elements

*Some further reading:*

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/
- http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `live()` function and pass `click` as the event to handle.

`.click()` applies to all objects which currently exist

`.live()` applies to all current and future objects.

```
$('a.reply').live( 'click' , function (e){ ... } );
```

More reading: http://api.jquery.com/live/

**UPDATE**

As others have pointed out, `live()` is deprecated and you should use `on()`

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: live is deprecated (since version 1.4.4!)

Comment: Well, I'll be. I had no idea. It will still work as of now, and has the same principles as the `.on()` function. It's be nice if jquery's website made that more obvious, aside from just tagging it 'deprecated'

Comment: Please read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/) you added, to learn why `live` is deprecated.

Comment: according to that link `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.` - not 1.4.4 as you stated. I would have been surprised if I hadn't known about this since 1.4.4. And when I say they should make it more obvious, I am talking about perhaps a yellow box at the top of the page alerting you not to use the function anymore. Not a one-liner half-way down the page. I don't make a habit of re-reading documentation once I understand it. :)

Comment: Im not disagreeing with you - I just have no idea how I would have known if you didn't tell me. I even looked at the docs page for `live` this morning. Didnt see anything.

Comment: perhaps jQuery should `console.log('this is depricated')` for all of the depricated functions. they could remove that from the minified versions... that would be cool.

Answer (score 1):

Elements added to the DOM have to event handlers attached. You need to attach them AFTER your AJAX call, or in advance using jQuery's `.on()` or `.live()` functionality.